# Tooltip display difficulties

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, tooltip

I'm trying to resolve a problem that I encountered with the creation of a tooltip interface in a website I'm developing. I constructed the tooltips with help of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The script is pretty simple as you can see in the fiddle underneath, and is based on a toggle behaviour, on witch a trigger element open a pop-up tooltip.

**[`jsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/chiappe_di_bronzo/axcjnrku/3/)**

Now! My problem is that i can't figure out how to place the trigger on the top of everything so they are not hidden by the pop-ups! Let me explain. Since the pop-up, even when they are off, sometimes cover the trigger elemets they (the triggers) just result not clickable. is like they are hidden behind invisible pop-ups. Here is a link of how is right now online.

http://271116.lucamule.com/studio-1

I hope you can see the problem! Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: You need to place your tooltips away when they're not active. Something like `left: -10000px;` in your css. Now, when active, you can add a class, which changes the `left` value appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the .pop-ups to "block" as soon as it initializes. `$("div.pop-up").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})`

If you want to show/hide, I would recommend using .fadeIn/.fadeOut: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: Hey @PeterChon!
thx for the Answer! I'm tring to figure ot the fadeIn and out, but just can't. Can you give me a hint how to resolve the script?

Comment: Basically, onclick you can apply the .fadeToggle() method.

Comment: $(el).on(click: function(){ $(elem).fadeToggle() });

Comment: thax you very much! really helpful! :D